# Laravel 4.x: How to delete a file?

Tags: php, file-io, laravel-4

I've got an table name's image.It has id,name,url and timestamp field.

here is my code:

```
$image=Image::find($id);
$url=$image->url;
if(unlink("$url")){
    $image->delete();
    return true;
}else
    return false;
```

It doesn't work so I echo the url i've got:

```
http://localhost/project/public/uploads/gallery/1/_DSC845645490.jpg
```

But when i check it:

```
if(file_exists(Image::find($id)->url)){
            return 'has image';
        }else{
            return 'no image';
        }
```

I've got 'no image' althought I can show that Image on web browser

Why is that???Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked everytime i used

```
File::delete(public_path('img/slider/').$delete_image);
```

here **$delete_image** is name of the file and path written in **public_path()** method is the path which begins from root folder of laravel **yourProject/public/**

Answer (score 0):

There's method in class Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem (See http://laravel.com/api/4.1/ and search for 'filesystem').

You can call its method *delete* like this

```
File::delete(path/to/file/relative/to/public/folder);
```

BTW: Maybe even your code is good but what do you have in url field? If it's relative paht, you have to also prepend it with something like

```
<?php 
  if( file_exists( $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/my_images/abc.jpg"))  { 
    ... 
  } 
?>
```

(Example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: I would suggest using `is_writable()`, as you need it to be writable to be able to delete it.

Comment: My url field is the absolute path like: http://localhost/project/public/uploads/gallery/1/_DSC845645490.jpg

Comment: I used File::delete() too and it didn't work. That method uses unlink() too :https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php

Comment: I used is_writable() and it returns false. So how to enable it?

Comment: Ok here's the problem. I shouldn't use the absolute path when using chmod or unlink. The url like 'localhost/project/public/uploads/gallery/1/_DSC845645490.jpg' should be '/uploads/gallery/1/_DSC845645490.jpg'. Thanks everyone